# Java: Is `while (true) { ... }` loop in a thread bad? What's the alternative?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, loops, message-passing

Is `while (true) { ... }` loop in threads bad? What's the alternative?

**Update; what I'm trying to to...**

I have ~10,000 threads, each consuming messages from their private queues. I have one thread that's producing messages one by one and putting them in the correct consumer's queue. Each consumer thread loops indefinitely, checking for a message to appear in their queue and process it.

Inside Consumer.java:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Message msg = messageQueue.poll();
        if (msg != null) {
            ... // do something with the message
        }
    }
}
```

The Producer is putting messages inside Consumer message queues at a rapid pace (several million messages per second). Consumers should process these messages as fast as possible!

Note: the `while (true) { ... }` is terminated by a KILL message sent by the Producer as its last message. However, my question is about the proper way to do this message-passing...

**Please see [the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367383/java-high-performance-message-passing-single-producer-single-consumer), regarding this design.**

Comment: Why don't you give more detail about what you are trying to achieve and we will tell you if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: `@Ryan:` Updated; please take a look!

Comment: 10000 threads seems like a bad idea, since there may be overhead associated with each thread...

Comment: `@Colen:` Please see my new question, as I thought it was a bad idea too... What's the alternative? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367383/java-high-performance-message-passing-single-producer-single-consumer

Comment: The overhead of 10k threads will be extreme

Comment: `Willi Schönborn:` Then, what's the alternative?

Comment: if you use a while instead of an if statement inside your thread - does that mean that you create a new loop everytime your thread runs?

Answer (score 21):

Instead of looping forever and breaking or returning, you might choose to check the interrupted status.

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        doWork();
        wait(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

If your threads are tasks managed by an ExecutorService, you can have them all end gracefully simply by calling shutdownNow().

Comment: Better use Thread.sleep(1000) than wait(), cz wait requires the object to be blocked first.

Comment: Hey. That's nice... But what if I want to kill the thread from `update` method of an observer... I don't know how much time it will take to trigger the method so a random `wait(1000)` won't work here....

Answer (score 9):

```
while (!stop_running) { ... }
```

...perhaps? A some sort of exit flag is often used to control thread running.

Comment: If you do this, make sure stop_running uses the volatile keyword. See Java Concurrency In Practice, section 7.1.

Comment: this seems simple, but the issue: how does `stop_running` change to false after that loop begins? That's what I think most people are wondering

Answer (score 7):

Not inherently, no.  You can always bail using `break` or `return`.  Just make sure you actually do (at some point)

The problem is what happens when your thread has nothing to do?  If you just loop around and around checking a condition, your thread will eat up the whole CPU doing nothing.   So make sure to use `wait` to cause your thread to block, or `sleep` if you don't have anything to `wait` on.

Comment: Is it really that much CPU though?

Comment: @Clocker - try it yourself, but yes, I believe a busy wait would use 100% of one CPU core.

Comment: @Clocker This is called a _busy loop_ and uses all the cpu power it can get from a single core.  In the old days, where cpu's only _had_ a single core this could bring your system to its knees, and developers therefore benefitted greatly from a two-cpu system.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the definition of "bad".  It means that the person trying to read the code has to look elsewhere for the reason that the loop is terminated.  That may make it less readable.

This mentality taken to the extreme results in the COMEFROM keyword.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM

```
10 COMEFROM 40
20 INPUT "WHAT IS YOUR NAME? "; A$
30 PRINT "HELLO, "; A$
40 REM
```

Answer (score 2):

First up, the straight answer to this problem by Dough Lea:

> It is almost never a good idea to use bare spins waiting for values of variables. Use Thread.onSpinWait, Thread.yield, and/or blocking synchronization to better cope with the fact that "eventually" can be a long time, especially when there are more threads than cores on a system.

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html

**Thead.onSpinWait was introduced with Java 9.** It could look like this.

```
while (true) {
    while (messageQueue.peek() == null) {
       Thread.onSpinWait();
    }
    // do something with the message
}
```

> By invoking this method within each iteration of a spin-wait loop construct, the calling thread indicates to the runtime that it is busy-waiting. The runtime may take action to improve the performance of invoking spin-wait loop constructions.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait--

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'll want to `wait` on a resource of some kind to do work, which hides actual threading details from you. It sounds like you wanted to implement your own [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).

[Here's some tutorial about locking I found I google.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-thread.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have the termination condition on the `while (...)` line, but sometimes the termination condition is something you can only test somewhere deep inside the loop. Then that's what `break` is for (or exceptions). In fact maybe your thread must run forever until your program terminates (with `System.exit`); then `while (true)` is definitely right.

But maybe you're asking about what should go inside the loop. You need to make sure to include some blocking operation, i.e., some function call where your thread will wait for someone else (another thread, another program, the OS) to do something. This is typically `Condition.wait` if you're programming with locks, or reading from a message queue, or reading from a file or network socket, or some other blocking I/O operation.

Note that `sleep` is generally *not* good enough. You can't know when other participants are going to do something, so there's no way to avoid waking up too often (thus burning up CPU time needlessly) or too seldom (thus not reacting to events in a timely way). Always design your system so that when a thread has completed its job, it notifies whoever is waiting on that job (often with `Condition.signal` or by joining).

Answer (score 1):

`while (true)` isn't bad if there is a way to exit the loop otherwise the call will run indefinitely.

For 10000 threads doing the `while(true)` call is bad practice...why don't you have a `sleep()` on the thread to allow other threads to run or an exit strategy if the thread finish running?

Answer (score 1):

Although all the above answers are correct, I want to suggest this one as I came across this situation myself:
You can use a flag say:

```
isRunning=true;
while(isRunning){
   //do Something
}
```

Later, make sure that isRunning is set to false after you are done reading from the buffer or data file.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with a class attribute boolean called 'done', then the threads' run methods look like

```
done = false;
while( !done ) {
    // ... process stuff
}
```

You can then set done=true to kill the loop. This can be done from inside the loop, or you can have another method that sets it, so that other threads can pull the plug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are busy waiting, assuming a standard `BlockingQueue`. Use `take` instead of `poll`.

Other than that, `for (;;)` is nicer than `while (true)`, IMO.

Comment: using take will keep waiting for the message to come right? and poll(100) will just wait for 100 ms and continue execution. So, isn't poll(100) better than take?

Answer (score -2):

If I were do what you are talking about I would try this:

```
private Object lock = new Object();    

public void run(){
    while(true){
        synchronized(lock){
            Message msg = messageQueue.poll();
            if (msg != null) {
                ... // do something with the message
            }else{
                try{
                    lock.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to make sure that you don't get any concurrent modification exepction on your messageQueue, as well as when there is no message you will not be using CPU time in the while(true) loop. Now you just need to make sure that when you do add something to your messageQueue you can call `lock.notifyAll()` so that the thread will know to run again.

Comment: That's not so great with a shared queue.

Comment: Use LinkedBlockingQueue for the messageQueue and it wil be thread safe, no need for the lock or synchronized block above.  Just call take instead of poll if you want to block while the queue is empty. You can alternatively use poll with a timeout if you want to implement timeouts.

Comment: Also swallowing the interrupted exception means your thread can never exit unless a RuntimeException occurs.